# Problems with passing variables to a partial

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm using the partial "infowindow" (app/view/tech/_infowindow.html.erb) to populate a google map marker using:

```
new_marker = GMarker.new([t.lat, t.lng], :icon => icon, :title => t.summary, :info_window => (render_to_string :partial => "infowindow", :object => t))
```

but i'm getting a very odd error.  When I simply put:

```
<%= debug(infowindow) %>
```

I get the full output of the hash.  But when I try to reference any of the individual attributes like:

```
<%= infowindow.summary %>
```

I get thrown an undefined method `summary' for nil:NilClass even though the attribute shows up in the debug output for the entire hash.  Why can I only access the entire hash and not its individual attributes in the partial?

EDIT: The top part of the returned hash:

```
!ruby/object:Ticket 
attributes:
```

The model being used is a Ticket object if that helps.

Answer (score 2):

What you are trying to do is call the method `summary` on the infowindow hash which does not exist in the Hash Class and hence the error. To access individual hash elements try this

```
<%= infowindow["summary"] %>
```

Comment: It *could* be available as a method too if the plugin writer was smart.

Comment: I'm still getting an error that now it's a nil object...  The variable being passed is a Ticket object with, for example, a summary column.  If the infowindow is the local variable for the Ticket object, why can't I just do infowindow.summary in the same model.attribute syntax used elsewhere?

Comment: did you make progress with the problem... i have a similar problem with RSpec + partial + view, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4695183/rspec2-partial-view-gives-nilnilclass-why